# Handling null arguments in a factory class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a `Factory` class that gives out instances of `ResponseImpl` class. It accepts one `Destination` class and up to four `Source` classes. At least one of the four `Source` classes should be not `null`.

So, instead of asking calling program to pass `null`s in the arguments to `Factory` class, I have overloaded the method to accept at least one up to four `Source` classes. But, something tells me that this way of doing it is not a good idea. Although this works, I feel like this can be handled better.

Could you let me know how to make the following piece of code better?

```
public static Response initResponse(final Destination destination, final Source1 source1) {
    return initResponse(destination, source1, null, null, null);
}

public static Response initResponse(final Destination destination, final Source1 source1, final Source2 source2) {
    return initResponse(destination, source1, source2, null, null);
}

public static Response initResponse(final Destination destination, final Source1 source1, final Source2 source2, final Source3 source3) {
    return initResponse(destination, source1, source2, source3, null);
}

public static Response initResponse(final Destination destination, final Source1 source1, final Source2 source2, final Source3 source3, final Source4 source4) {
    try {
        if(source1 == null && source2 == null && source3 == null && source4 == null) {
            throw new ABODataException("Atleast one source has to be not null");
        }
        return ResponseImplManager.getInstance(destination, source1, source2, source3, source4);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ABODataException("Unable to instantiate Response:"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit problematic to refactor when the parameters are from four different types of classes. I have a couple of alternative approaches for you though, pick one if you like one.

One option would be to make your classes `Source1`, `Source2`, etc. implement one common interface. Perhaps this would even simplify your `ResponseImplManager.getInstance`? If they would be of the same interface (or shared superclass would also be possible of course), then you could use a method like this:

```
public static Response initResponse(final Destination destination,
    final SourceInterface... sources) {
    // sources is treated as an array here
}
```

Or you could send a list of sources

```
public static Response initResponse(final Destination destination,
    final List<SourceInterface> sources)
```

Another option would be to use a [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Whichever way you go in, I got one more suggestion. Use the two-parameter constructor for Exceptions to provide "Caused by" information, this will give you a more detailed stack trace

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ABODataException("Unable to instantiate Response", e);

        // or use this:
        throw new ABODataException("Unable to instantiate Response: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

Comment: I was going to add a edit about using variable arguments too but then I noticed that the classes were not the same and then reached the same conclusion as your. a big +1 for you.

Comment: Looks like using Builder pattern is the way to go. I didn't think about that.

Comment: @would_like_to_be_anon That's what you have us for, to think for you after you've done the initial thinking :)

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me that you are not quite making good use of exceptions and as long as I believe it is possible that you are disrespecting some principles. First things first, you really should be using `IllegalArgumentException` because that is the java standard exception class for invalid arguments. You shouldn't also throw a exception and then catch it so your throw statement should be outside the try block. Why should you ever raise a error to treat it imeadiatly? You should avoid it instead!

```
public static Response initResponse(final Destination destination, final Source1 source1, final Source2 source2, final Source3 source3, final Source4 source4) {
    if(source1 == null && source2 == null && source3 == null && source4 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Atleast one source has to be not null");
    }
    try {
        return ResponseImplManager.getInstance(destination, source1, source2, source3, source4);
    } catch (Exception e) {//if possible catch the specific type of the exception that is thrown by getInstance thought I don't see it as a huge issue as you don't have any other method calls
        throw new ABODataException("Unable to instantiate Response:"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```